# How can I create a segue from a collectionview cell to another collectionview cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, segue

I want to create a segue from my collectionview cell to another collectionview cell from another viewcontroller. For example when the first cell is tapped i want to go to first cell of the other collectionview from another viewcontroller. Or when the second cell is tapped i want to go to second cell. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly have a segue from a collection view cell in one viewcontroller go to another cell in a different view controller.    However it should be possible to achieve what you you want by doing something similar to the following:

Parent ViewController

1) Add a property selectedIndexPath of type NSIndexPath

2) Setup in Storyboard (or in code) that this view controller implements the UICollectionViewDelegate

3)  Implement the didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate method for your Collection View

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
}
```

4) Pass the selectedIndexPath value to your 2nd View Controller

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     // :: Should do other checking - if we have segues to other screens 
     SecondViewController *secondViewController = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
     secondViewController.initialDisplayedCellIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
}
```

}

SecondViewController Code

1) Add a property initialDisplayCellIndexPath of type NSIndexPath

2) Override viewWillAppear

(This is assuming that your collectionView property is named collectionView)

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:initialDisplayCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
```

Basically what the above is doing is doing a normal segue from one view controller to your second view controller - triggered in the code as a result of clicking on a cell.   As part of the prepareForSegue we can pass data to the second view controller (which in this case is the indexPath of the selected item).   Then when the second viewcontroller is displayed we then tell the collection view to scroll to where we want to go.

Hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did everything you said but when i tap the cell it crashes. When i comment out scrollToItemAtIndexPath part inside viewWillAppear the segue works but all of the cells go to first cell from the second view controller

Comment: This is the error i get:    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: